# How do I convert a libxml2 xmlParserErrors code to a printable string?

Tags: error-handling, runtime-error, libxml2

The libxml2 error module contains a substantial enum, xmlParserErrors, with several hundred possible error codes. Is there a function in libxml2 that returns a string corresponding to a given error code (member of the xmlParserErrors enum)?

Answer (score 0):

There's no such function, but sometimes you can get more information with [`xmlGetLastError`](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlerror.html#xmlGetLastError):

```
xmlErrorPtr error = xmlGetLastError();
printf("Error: %s\n", error->message);
```